# Unable to parse json into an object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am not sure how to parse the following json into a strongly typed object.

The JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "71161": {
      "air_by_date": 0,
      "anime": 0,
      "cache": {
        "banner": 1,
        "poster": 1
      },
      "indexerid": 71161,
      "language": "en",
      "network": "CBS",
      "next_ep_airdate": "",
      "paused": 0,
      "quality": "SD",
      "show_name": "name",
      "sports": 0,
      "status": "Ended",
      "subtitles": 0,
      "tvdbid": 71161
    },
    "71211": {
      "air_by_date": 0,
      "anime": 0,
      "cache": {
        "banner": 1,
        "poster": 1
      },
      "indexerid": 71211,
      "language": "en",
      "network": "ABC (US)",
      "next_ep_airdate": "",
      "paused": 0,
      "quality": "SD",
      "show_name": "name2",
      "sports": 0,
      "status": "Ended",
      "subtitles": 0,
      "tvdbid": 71211
    },
}
```

The issue is the number `71161` this can be different for each JSON response.

Comment: What happens if you use JSON.parse(your_json_string);

Comment: @pantuofermo The Json is valid and will parse. But how do I turn it into a strongly types object?

Comment: You'll have to define `data` as `Dictionary<string, YourObjectData>`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I think you want to use the popular Json.NET library from Newtonsoft. You can use nuget to download it. Once you have the library referenced you can turn a json string into a strongly type object by doing this: Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(jsonString);

Comment: Along with what haim770 pointed out and my solution, that should get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks @haim770 that's what I was looking for.

Comment: May I ask what did you try that didn't work, so you were "unable" to parse the data?

Comment: @TamasHegedus I couldn't define the correct type to deseralise the data into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Json.NET from Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Let the `data` property be a `Dictionary<int, Item>`, the library will handle the conversion of keys from `string` to `int`:

```
class Program
{
    class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
    class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
        public Dictionary<int, Item> Data { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(@"{ ""data"": { ""123"": { ""status"": ""Ended"" } } }");
        Console.WriteLine(root.Data[123].Status); // prints "Ended"
    }
}
```